# HttpActionContext.get_Request() method not found when using Microsoft Asp.NET Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I am trying to add [Microsoft Extensions Dependency Injection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) to an existing ASP.NET WebApi/Owin project.

Following [this blog post](https://scottdorman.github.io/2016/03/17/integrating-asp.net-core-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4/), I have added the `ConfigureServices` function, implemented `DependencyResolver`, and made `HttpConfiguration` instance to use it.

Also I added all the non-abstract controllers to DI, and ensured they are instantiated using the DI mechanism.

But after all these actions, requests to the application return error 500 with exception

> Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext.get_Request()'.

I get the same result even if I just add the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package to NuGet and don't change any other code. After I remove it, everything works fine.

Here is the code I added into Startup.cs:

The DependcyResolver implementation:

```
public class DefaultDependencyResolver :
    System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver, 
    System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyScope
{
    protected IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public DefaultDependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void Dispose() { }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.serviceProvider.GetServices(serviceType);
    }

}
```

Adding controllers to DI:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();   
    IEnumerable<Type> controllers = typeof(Startup).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
       .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
       .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
          || t.Name.EndsWith("Controller", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    foreach (var c in controllers)
    {
        services.AddTransient(c);
    }
}
```

Creating ServiceCollection, calling services configuration and setting DependencyResolver:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
    // ...
    HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();

    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    ConfigureServices(services);

    httpConfiguration.DependencyResolver = 
        new DefaultDependencyResolver(services.BuildServiceProvider());

    WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfiguration);
    app.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);
}
```

The exception stacktrace:

```
at myCompany.myProduct.Controllers.SomeController.Get(String id, String offline)
at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Always post the _full stack trace_ of the exception _and_ its inner exceptions.

Comment: Also note that there is a bug in your `DefaultDependencyResolver.GetServices` method, since `IDependencyScope.GetServices` should never return `null`, while `IServiceProvider.GetServices(Type)` will return `null` when no registrations exist for the specified `Type`.

Comment: Please add information such as the stack trace, message and exception type of _all the inner exceptions_ as well.

Comment: @Steven I would like to give you more, but due to complicated debug process, that's all exception information I can post. Also, thanks for pointing `DefaultDependencyResolver` bug, I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to add binding redirects to your web.config file.
Check the following links with more information on the issue:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3615

https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection

Answer (score 2):

I've installed 'System.Net.Http' from nuget (v 4.3.3) and updated my .csproj file to force msbuild to use specified dll:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.3\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

It resolved the problem.