# I can't install system.net.http

Tags: c#, system.net

I have a `web api 2` Project in `.net 4.6.1` in which I am trying to add a custom `ValidateModelAttribute` but I get a warning for the `system.net.http 4.0` assembly.

[image]

Here are the assembly properties

[image]

I have tried removing and reinstalling the package multiple times but I keep getting the same warning.  And when I try to use the `CustomModelAttribute` the api call from Postman throws the following error

> {
>
> "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>
> "ExceptionMessage": "Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext.get_Request()'.",
>
> "ExceptionType": "System.MissingMethodException",
>
> "StackTrace": "   at myapi.Api.Mvc.Filters.ValidateModelAttribute.OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext
>   actionContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext
>   actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of
>   stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n 
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
>   }

Here is the custom attribute

```
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace myapi.Api.Mvc.Filters
{
    public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpActionContext.get\_Request() method not found when using Microsoft Asp.NET Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46887799/httpactioncontext-get-request-method-not-found-when-using-microsoft-asp-net-de)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. All I had to do was right click on `system.net.http` assembly and click properties. Then I set `copy local` to `true`